# I need to be able to filter Project information by Project Name and Team Member name from several Team Member Sheets onto a central Overview Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm hoping someone can help, please.

Relatively experienced novice here....

I'll try to be as concise as possible.

I am building a (google sheets) spreadsheet to track project progress and time spent by different Team Members.
(each team member currently has a different tab on the sheet.

What I am trying to achieve is a separate Project Overview sheet where the following happens:

Filter by (currently two drop-downs drawn from a settings tab) Project name AND Team Member (with an option to also select ALL Team Members)

The idea of the above is that the Project Overview Sheet will show you all rows for that project that feature on a Team Members (or all members) Tab/s, along with current status (in progress, in review, completed etc) and time spent on each Project task.

This is currently not working and the importrange is showing duplicated information in singular cells.

My current, not working solution is:

Tab for each Team Member - top of each project section has a project name dropdown. Column B in this sheet =cell where the Project Dropdown is to connect project name to row and be able to draw each row for the Query.

ALL MEMBERS TAB (Staff Import) - this uses an Importrange for each Team Member tab at 500 row intervals for Project Overview Sheet to Query

The formula I am using for this is:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJ2oCWl6MciX3ND-nJ27_ucgPbrXLi460iewJ_LjUMM/edit#gid=531313102", "Dan!A7:P500"),
"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16")

'Dan' = Team Member/Tab name

PROJECT OVERVIEW TAB - two drop downs; one with Team Member (or ALL) name and one with project name. This should Query Col2 for project name AND Col1 for Team Member name from the All Members Tab so then the POS will then display all task lines from any or all Team Members so I am able to see status/progress and time spent.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJ2oCWl6MciX3ND-nJ27_ucgPbrXLi460iewJ_LjUMM/edit#gid=1424423462", "Staff Import!A5:P"),
"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16 WHERE Col2 = '"& A1 &"' AND Col1 = '"& B1 &"' ")

A1 = Project name (Dropdown from Settings Tab)
A2 = Team Member name (Dropdown from Settings Tab)

SETTINGS TAB - Project names to use dropdown from range
```

.

I had the importrange function working when only filtered by Project name. Since adding the Team Member filter it is not working at all.

I would be really grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you.